# Pull request from a modified fork

Tags: git, github

I've forked a project on Github, and made changes to match my own requirements.

Now, I've found a bug that we both share (upstream project and my fork). If I try to make a pull request, it obviously includes all my changes.

I've thought of making a new branch where I revert all my changes before fixing the bug, but this doesn't seem right.

Maybe I should keep the `master` branch synced with the upstream project?

What's the best way to handle this situation?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd create a dedicated fix branch for the issue based on the forked original branch:

1. create a branch based on the upstream master branch (where you forked off)
2. `git cherry-pick` your fix into that branch
3. Create the pull request for that branch that holds only your fix

If development on the original repo progressed, it would be even more comfortable for the maintainer of the original repo if you'd fetch it's current state and apply your fix there, i.e. create a fresh fork just for your fix, `cherry-pick` your fix there and create a pull-request for this forked repo.